# How to read a csv file using pyarrow in python

Tags: pyarrow

I have made a connection to my HDFS using the following command

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

fs = pa.hdfs.connect(self.namenode, self.port, user=self.username, kerb_ticket = self.cert)
```

I'm using the following command to read a parquet file

```
fs.read_parquet()
```

but there is not read method for regular text files (e.g. a csv file). How can I read a csv file using pyarrow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file-like object and use the CSV module directly.  See [pyarrow.csv.read_csv](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.read_csv.html)

Comment: I think this function is for reading csv files from local drive, but I need to read it from HDFS. Where should I use the HDFS connection (fs in my cases)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a spark session to connect to hdfs, then read it from there.

```
ss = SparkSession.builder.appName(...)
csv_file = ss.read.csv('/user/file.csv')
```

Another way is to open the file first, then read it using csv.csv_read
Here is what I used at the end.

```
from pyarrow import csv
file = 'hdfs://user/file.csv'

with fs.open(file, 'rb') as f:
    csv_file = csv.read_csv(f)
```